# Sets Modulo Equivalence Relations

Tags: elementary-set-theory, equivalence-relations

I am stuck on this question and would greatly appreciate any help:

Recall, for an arbitrary set $S$ and equivalence relation $\equiv$ on $S$, $S/\equiv$ denotes the set of equivalence classes in $S$.  Consider the relation $\sim$ on the plane $\mathbb{R}^2 = \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ defined in the following way:  for $\vec{x}, \vec{y} \in \mathbb{R}^2$, say $\vec{x} \sim \vec{y}$ if $\vec{x}-\vec{y} \in \mathbb{Z}^2$.  Show that $\sim$ is an equivalence relation, and describe $\mathbb{R}^2 / \sim$.

Comment: What's giving you problems? Reflexivity, Symmetry, Transitivity...?

Answer (score 0):

You've defined

$$\binom ab\sim\binom xy\iff\begin{cases}x-a\in\Bbb Z\\{}\\\text{and also}\\{}\\y-b\in\Bbb Z\end{cases}$$

For transitivity we have:

$$\binom ab\sim\binom cd\sim\binom xy\implies \begin{cases}c-a\\d-b\end{cases}\in\Bbb Z\;\;\text{and also}\;\;\begin{cases}x-c\\y-d\end{cases}\in\Bbb Z$$

and for example

$$x-a=(x-c)+(c-a)\;\ldots\;\;\text{complete and end the exercise}$$